# Incremental search in all visible buffers

Tags: highlighting, isearch

Here's a feature I always wanted: I have two buffers opened side-by-side and I'd like to be able to start an incremental search in one of those buffers, but in a way which highlights results in both buffers.

This would be extra useful to make sure I didn't make a typo - it's sometimes hard for me to be sure just by looking at the text. Alternatively, something like idle highlight but for all visible buffers would work as well.

Is there a package for that? Can it be done?

Comment: Try `multi-occur` or `helm-multi-swoop` as a workaround while you don't get an answer.

Comment: Additionally if you have swiper/ivy, `swiper-all` searches all buffers and has a nice preview for each result similar to helm.

Answer (score 2):

- You can search multiple buffers using ordinary Isearch (commands `multi-isearch-buffers` and `multi-isearch-buffers-regexp`. But it searches them one at a time.
- If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview#SearchMultipleBuffersFilesAndBookmarks) to search multiple buffers (or bookmarks or files) at the same time, which means highlighting them all at the same time.

Comment: To help out, the commands are: `multi-isearch-buffers` or `multi-isearch-buffers-regexp`. You have to manually select each buffer to search so that might be a down side.

Comment: @Greth: Mentioned the Isearch commands for multi-search. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a solution that worked exactly as I wanted. So I made a thing https://github.com/ignacy/idle-highlight-in-visible-buffers-mode